# Is it possible to get access to keyword arguments as a Hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I know I can do:

```
class Parent
  def initialize(args)
    args.each do |k,v|
      instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v)
    end
  end
end
class A < Parent
  def initialize(attrs)
    super(attrs)
  end
end
```

But I'd want to use keyword arguments to make more clear which hash keys method may accept (and have validation saying that this key isn't supported).

So I can write:

```
class A
  def initialize(param1: 3, param2: 4)
    @param1 = param1
    @param2 = param2
  end
end
```

But is it possible to write something shorter instead of `@x = x; @y = y; ...` to initialize instance variables from passed keyword arguments? Is it possible to get access to passed keyword arguments as a Hash?

Comment: What's the purpose of using a hash if you have keyword arguments?

Comment: @DaveNewton, programmatic access to all the keyword arguments at once.

Comment: @DaveNewton to be able to easier initialize instance variables with the same names as keyword arguments' keys

Answer (score 5):

Not something I would recommend using (because `eval`!), but this is the only way I can think of, as I don't think there's a way to get the value of a local variable without `eval`.

```
class A
  def initialize(param1: 3, param2: 4)
    method(__method__).parameters.each do |type, name|
      if type == :key
        instance_variable_set "@#{name}", eval("#{name}")
      end
    end
  end
end

p A.new param1: 20, param2: 23
p A.new
```

Output:

```
#<A:0x007fd7e21008d0 @param1=20, @param2=23>
#<A:0x007fd7e2100218 @param1=3, @param2=4>
```

`method` returns a [`Method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Method.html) object for the passed in symbol, `__method__` returns the name of the current method, and `Method#parameters` returns an array describing the parameters the method accepts. Here I only set the parameters which have the type `:key` (named params).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about `__method__`. I wanted to make amount of my code less and more readable but this won't make it more readable  as it seems I can't move this code to `Parent`

Comment: `eval("#{name}")` should be equal to `name`, no? Why do you need `eval`?

Comment: In Ruby version >= 2.1 you can do it without `eval`.  Replace the `eval("#{name}")` with `binding.local_variable_get(name)`.

Comment: `eval("#{name}")` **is not** equal to `name`.  `name` is a :symbol so you would just end up doing, for example, `@param1 = :param1`