# How do I get the value of a keyname argument from a symbol in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

As an experiment in Ruby metaprograming lets say I have a class `Pet` which takes several keyword arguments.

I then want to dynamically assign the keyword arguments to attributes:

```
class Pet
  def initialize(name:, age: 0)
    args = method(__method__).parameters.map { |arg| arg[1] }
    args.each do |name| 
      instance_variable_set("@#{key.to_s}", eval(name.to_s)) # Is it possible to do this without eval?
    end
  end
end
```

However I would like to avoid using `eval`.
Is it possible to get the parameters the function is called with like the `arguments` object in Javascript?

**EDIT**:

Why keyword arguments? The idea here being that the allowed and default arguments be specified in the `initializer` declaration. Although probably not the best idea in the world it would be kind of cool since you could get the signature in an IDE inspection without using docblocks.

**Please note:** I am very aware this is possible both by using a `splat` or `hash` as an argument instead. That is not the question.

Comment: Related to [Is it possible to get access to keyword arguments as a Hash in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614825/is-it-possible-to-get-access-to-keyword-arguments-as-a-hash-in-ruby). But I want to see if it is possible to get an answer which does not use `eval`

Comment: Rejected edit since it is pertinent that this is an experiment.

Comment: I would agree with leaving in the preamble about this being an experiment, as nothing like this has any reason to exist outside of experimentation. Your initializer should simply *not use keyword arguments*, and instead just accept a normal hash.

Comment: Small correction: the string you pass to `instance_variable_set` has to include the `@`

Comment: Also, `name` is a poor choice of loop variable, as it conflicts with one of your named parameters; `Pet.new(name: anything)` will result in `@name` being set to `:name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword arguments are added as local variables, thus, you could get the value using the current `binding`:

```
class Pet
  def initialize(name:, age: 0)
    args = method(__method__).parameters.map { |arg| arg[1] }

    args.each do |key| 
      value = binding.local_variable_get(key)
      instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value)
    end
  end
end
```

Some caveats apply though. Using the `binding`, you can access details about a certain variable scope. While this is vert powerful, it is generally rather slow in Ruby, in fact, supporting `binding` at all is one of the greatest performance killers in about all Ruby implementations.

Furthermore, accessing local variables that way has the potential for serious security issues as it could be used to access unrelated system state. Be very careful, which variables you expose this way.

Finally, the binding is always generated at the exact point where it is called. That means, if you assign a new value to e.g. the `name` variable before calling `binding`, it will return that new value, not the original method argument. Because of that, I changed your block argument name to `key`.

Comment: Accepted for the extra explanation about the caveats of binding.

Answer (score 1):

You can nominally avoid `eval` here using `binding.local_variable_get`, which does exactly what it sounds like.

```
class Pet
  def initialize(name:, age: 0)
    args = method(__method__).parameters.map { |arg| arg[1] }
    args.each do |name| 
      instance_variable_set(:"@#{name}", binding.local_variable_get(name))
    end
  end
end
```

Of course, this gets much cleaner if you just take a hash. The interface is identical; the caller can still do `Pet.new(name: 'Rover', age: 5)`.

Comment: Works but I realised I needed to change the local variable name in the `args.each` to something else than `name`. Otherwise it  gives you something like `<Pet:0x000001029155c0 @name=:name, @age=5>`. Thanks!

Comment: I mentioned that in my other comment, @papirtiger. :)